# Unable to resolve static method

Tags: android, json, steam-condenser

I have been messing around with steam-condenser and have made an android app to test out some small bits like grabbing achievements but have run into problems with one of the classes inside the `.jar` file.

The method imports `org.json.JSONObject` and calls the `getNames()` method from the `json-java.jar` found at `json.org`. When compiling there is no errors but when I run the app and execute that method, it seems to point back to the default Android `org.json.JSONObject` which does *not* have a `getNames()` method.

The error can be seen here:

```
05-01 13:08:47.869: W/dalvikvm(1012): VFY: unable to resolve static method 13252: Lorg/json/JSONObject;.getNames (Lorg/json/JSONObject;)[Ljava/lang/String;
```

This eventually causes a runtime error and stops the application in it's tracks. Is there a way to make sure the `app/steam-condenser.jar` imports the correct library?

Comment: use google gson. the json jar has package name conflicts with the one android has.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you much without posting your code.

A quick guess would be your external JAR library is not being exported.  In Eclipse,

`right-click the project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export`

Be sure that your jar has a check by it, meaning that it is exported with your apk.